# how to exclude GWT dependency code from OSGI bundle generated by MAven+BND?

Tags: maven, osgi, vaadin

I have several Maven modules with Vaadin library dependency in the root pom.xml file.

I'm trying to build a set of OSGI bundles (1 per Maven module) using Maven+BND.

I added this to my "root" pom.xml file:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

unfortunately, the resulting JAR files (bundles) include GWT (com.google.gwt) classes. This 
1) makes the bundles huge, with lots of duplicated dependencies.
2) generated thousands of build warnings about "split packages".

QUESTION: how to prevent adding GWT classes into my Jar files?

I tried setting "scope" of GWT to "provided", setting "type" to "bundle", and even optional=true - didn't help.

here's the part of my root pom.xml, which is responsible for Vaadin/GWT stuff:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>mycompany.*</Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package>*.impl.*</Private-Package>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <!--                        <Bundle-Activator>com.alskor.publicpackage.MyActivator</Bundle-Activator>-->
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Compiles your custom GWT components with the GWT compiler -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Version 2.1.0-1 works at least with Vaadin 6.5 -->
            <version>2.3.0-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                <!--modules>
                    ..
                </modules-->
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/VAADIN/widgetsets
                </webappDirectory>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <runTarget>clean</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
                <noServer>true</noServer>
                <port>8080</port>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Updates Vaadin 6.2+ widgetset definitions based on project dependencies -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                        <!--
                        <modules>
                            <module>${package}.gwt.MyWidgetSet</module>
                        </modules>
                        -->
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcards in your Export-Package and Private-Package statements strike me as exceedingly dangerous. It's possible that the GWT packages are being dragged in because of the `*.impl.*` pattern in Private-Package.

Also you should *never* use wildcards in Export-Package: exports should be tightly controlled and versioned.

Comment: does it mean I can't define this "mycompany.*" pattern in the root file and have to have some BND config file in every module?

Comment: also, for some reasons I expected dependency "type=bundle" to not be included in the built JAR file, but I'm definitely wrong here. I see no effect on packaging when I set Maven dependency to "bundle". It may affect the way BND loads files from dependencies, I don't know...

Comment: In response to your first question… this is a matter of debate. In MY opinion, exported packages are very important and should be always be done explicitly and in a controlled way. Remember these are APIs that you offer to consumers, and therefore need to be maintained, versioned etc. Private packages are less of a concern because they are private, but wildcarding here is still a source of errors. Please read carefully the Maven Bundle Plugin documentation regarding the use of these instructions!

Comment: thanks, Neil. I have another problem now, which should probably be posted as a separate question: I can start Equinox server and access localhost:8080, but my Vaadin application is not accessible (404). I see that my webui.jar bundle does not contain any Vaadin resources (icons/themes). It only has classes and manifest.mf.  how can I add those resources to the bundle with Maven+BND?  I'm using standard Vaadin project layout: 
WebContent/META-INF
WebContent/VAADIN
WebContent/WEB-INF
pom.xml

I tried adding "bnd.bnd" file to the module with 
`Include-Resource: WebContent/Vaadin`
-no changes

Comment: I added '<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>WebContent</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>' to webui module pom.xml as an experiment. now the resources are added to the jar (except for Vaadin widgetsets), but bundles can't be started: the same package from "webui" is added to both "export" and "import" list in manifest.mf
another problem

Answer (score 0):

1. use mvn dependency:tree to see where the gwt dependency comes from
2. Add an `<excludes/>` element with an appropriate `<exclude/>` to the dependency in question to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem, as final war file exceeded almost 90MB ! 
One of the culprit was aforementioned jar, so I did this :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>widgetset</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```